# How can I fix this error, in this Get request, in my Angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript

√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

5 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2021-04-18T23:00:07.905Z - Hash: 1015f9357e983985a007 - Time: 1890ms

Error: src/app/api.service.ts:17:6 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Response, Response>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, Response>'.
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': headers, ok, redirected, status, and 12 more.

### 17     (map(this.extractData),
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
     public get(){  
       return this.httpClient.get(this.baseURL + '/api/admin/users').pipe
       (map(this.extractData),
       catchError(this.handleError)
       );
     }

     private extractData(res: Response) {
       let body = res;
       return body || {};
     }

     private handleError(error: Response | any) {
       let errMsg: string;
       if (error && error.name == 'HttpErrorResponse') {
       const err = error || '';
       errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
       } else {
       errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.statusText;
       }
       return throwError(errMsg);
      }
     }
```

---

Please let me know if additional information is needed.
"(`map(this.extractData`)" is underlined in VSC.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please post the type signature of the `extractData()` method? We don't necessarily need the whole function definition, just the parameter types and return type.

Comment: Done. Please let me know if I can provide anything further.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Angular CLI 11.2.8